# How to fetch selected assignments and laborer in Assignment Manager from an automation script MAXIMO

Tags: automation, maximo

I am creating a custom button in Assignment Manager to mimic the OOB Assign Labor button with a few modifications. I am trying to figure out how to fetch the selected laborer/s from the Labor List from my automation script. I am able to fetch the Work Order objects that are selected in the Work List by using mbo.getThisMboSet().getSelection() from the WMASSIGNMENT object. However I am still unable to find a method to fetch the selected laborers from the Labor List in Assignment Manager.

UPDATE
I've added the picture of Assignment Manager. I am trying to fetch the selected records from the Labor List section from an automation script. I can't find the object to call getSelection() from.

[image]

Comment: I am able to fetch the Work Order objects that are selected in the Work List by using `mbo.getThisMboSet().getSelection()` from the WMASSIGNMENT object. However I am still unable to find a method to fetch the selected laborers from the Labor List in Assignment Manager.

Comment: You can cycle through each Mbo in the set and look up the laborer if the Mbo `isSelected()`

Comment: @Preacher when I cycle through the selected Work Orders from `mbo.getThisMboSet().getSelection()` it is fetching the laborer that is currently associated with that work order, which in most cases is null.

Comment: Using App Designer, you should be able to find the Main Table for the application, then find the Relationship (from the Main Table) used by the Labor List table. You can then use the same relationship in your `mbo.getMboSet()` call in your script.